# Train object detector using dlib

Tags: c++, object-detection, dlib, precision-recall

I'm trying to train object detector based on [train_object_detector.cpp](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/02d8ebc903443e994d74c80c59a6c0886748cf1f/examples/train_object_detector.cpp) example using dlib library.

`time ./train_object_detector -tv -u 0 --threads 4 --flip data/training.xml`

```
Loading image dataset from metadata file data/training.xml
Number of images loaded: 78
objective:     45.1205
objective gap: 45.1167
risk:          45.1167
risk gap:      45.1167
num planes:    3
iter:          1

...

objective:     3.44535
objective gap: 0.00889926
risk:          2.99319
risk gap:      0.00889926
num planes:    60
iter:          157

Saving trained detector to object_detector.svm
Testing detector on training data...
Test detector (precision,recall,AP): 1 0 0 

Parameters used: 
  threads:                 4
  C:                       1
  eps:                     0.01
  target-size:             6400
  detection window width:  80
  detection window height: 80
  upsample this many times : 0
  trained using left/right flips.


real    3m17.072s
user    9m54.928s
sys 0m4.328s
```

`Test detector (precision,recall,AP): 1 0 0` means that true positives = 0 and false positives = 0?

And also when apply detector to any image from training set it can't detect any objects `Number of detections: 0.`

How to fix this?

Comment: 1. does each object on each image fit into 80x80 pixels box?
2. you should try different C and E prams

Comment: @Evgeniy 1. As I understand function `remove_unobtainable_rectangles` is check all bbox, so I don't need to check them manually? 2. Yes, changing `C` parameter helps and give something about  `Test detector (precision,recall,AP): 1 0.8 0.8`  if I keep increasing `C` I will get `1 1 1` , but as I understand I need to start from some `C` and keep increasing it while testing on separate testing set. Does dlib have this evaluation code to estimate optimal parameters?

Comment: Here is sample on how params can be found: http://dlib.net/model_selection_ex.cpp.html
With result 1 1 1, does your detector detect objects?

Comment: @Evgeniy yes, but as I understand `1 1 1` is overfit to training data, I will create test dataset and test detector on it.

Comment: See here http://dlib.net/faq.html#WhydoesnttheobjectdetectorItrainedwork maybe you didn't labeled exactly all objects from your dataset?